# Retrieve blob field from oracle database using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, blob

I have a table with the following definition in oracle

```
file_id varchar2(20)
file_content blob
```

Using the following PHP code I tried to retrieve the blob field but I get NULL

```
$file_id = '1324410597775';
$content = strtoupper('file_content');
$holder = ":holder";

$conn = oci_connect("user","password","tstring");
$sql = "select $holder from tbl_file_upload where file_id = '$file_id'";


$parse = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

oci_bind_by_name($parse, $holder, $content);

oci_execute($parse);

$row = oci_fetch_array($parse, OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
$lob = null;
if (is_object($row[$content])) {
     $lob = $row[$content]->load();
     $row[$content]->free();
     echo "Here";
}
```

I followed the example in this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18555/ch_twelve_blobs.htm

I'd appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is it throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT :holder` means that oci_fetch_array() cannot recognize `file_content` column in the answer. Note how the quoted tutorial uses `SELECT pic FROM ...` and not `SELECT :pic FROM ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    $conn = oci_pconnect('JRAHMAN89', 'jahid7654321', '10.2.1.18:1528/dbpblrnd');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}


$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select * from TAGM_SHARE_REG where BO_FOLIO_NO='3'");
oci_execute($stid);
while (($rowA = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) != false)
{ 
   header("Content-Type:" . $rowA['DOCTYPE']);
   echo $rowA['DOC'];

}

?>
```

It will work

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.